# Excel FILTER with multiple values

Tags: excel, filter

I am looking at the filter function that user Excel FILTER like this =FILTER(A2:D20,C2:C20=H2,"")

But, I would need more values for H2 (Include). I do not know how many include values I would need. I would need between 1 and 30 different values. How to solve this?

modifying =FILTER(A2:D20,**C2:C20=H:H**,"")  to include whole H column do not work nor =FILTER(A2:D20,**C2:C20=H2:H30**,"")
any idea how to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Use `ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2:C20,H2:H30,0))` as the condition.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot. I got one more possible solution: COUNTIF(H:H,C:C)>0

Comment: `COUNTIF(H:H,C:C)>0` is being forced to evaluate more than a million conditions, so I wouldn't recommend it.